# Format the formatted date for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I format this date `01 August, 15` for mysql DATE field. So I need this  `2015-08-01` format from `01 August, 15` this format in PHP. Tried following but not work

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01 August, 15'));
```

Comment: use `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01 August 2015'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `strtotime()` does not understand what `01 August, 15` means. Try it:

```
var_dump(strtotime('01 August, 15')); // false
```

The `15` at the end is too ambiguous; it could be the day of the month or a short year.

The easiest way to make this work is probably to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), like so:

```
$date   = '01 August, 15';
$parsed = DateTime::createFromFormat('d F, y', $date);
echo $parsed->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you control the format of the date then you could also make it easier to parse. Formatting it like `01 August 2015` would work, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the , out of the date and then use the strtotime function.
So:

```
$date = "01 August, 15";
$date = str_replace(",", "", $date);
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```